# i need help in regex

Tags: regex, matlab

so i have (matlab) code .. and of the lines doesnt have (;) after the line

i want to find that line

for a starter :

```
sad= sdfsdf ; %this is comment
sad = awaww ;
n= sdfdsfd ;
m = (asd  + adsf(asd,asd)) %this is comment
```

lets say i want to find the 4th line because it doesnt have (;) at the end of line ..

**so far im stuck at this :**

```
/(^[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%,_\+.()~#?&//= ]+)(?!;)$/gim
```

so this will work fine.. it will find the fourth line only
but what if i wanted (;) in middle of the line but not at end or before the comment .. ?

```
w=sss (;)aaa **;** % i dont want this line to be selected
w=sss (;)aaa %i want this line to be selected
```

http://regexr.com/3cfor

Comment: In your example, shouldn't the first commented line be a match as well since `;` is not at the end of the line?

Comment: With a slight changement your regex works fine for me: https://regex101.com/r/oA9gT5/1 (just escape the forward slash in the end like `\/`).

Comment: `^[^;]+$` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's find all lines which end with a semicolon:

```
^.+?;
```

optionally followed by horizontal whitespace:

```
^.+?;[ \t]*
```

and an optional comment:

```
^.+?;[ \t]*(?:%.*)?
```

This expression easily matches all the lines you *don't* want. So, inverse it:

```
^(?!.+?;[ \t]*(?:%.*)?$).+
```

Unfortunately, that's too easy. It fails to match lines which contain a semicolon in a comment. We could replace `.+?` with `[^%\r\n]+?` but this would fail on lines containing a `%` in a string.

If you need a more robust pattern, you'll have to account for all of this.

So let's start the same way, by defining what a "correct" line should look like. I'll use the PCRE syntax for atomic grouping, so you'll have to use `perl = TRUE`.

- A string is: `'(?>[^']+|'')*'`
- Other code (except string, comments and semicolons) is covered by: `[^%';\r\n]+`

So *"normal"* code is:

```
(?>[^%';\r\n]+|'(?>[^']+|'')*'|;)+?
```

Then, we add the required semicolon and optional comment:

```
(?>[^%';\r\n]+|'(?>[^']+|'')*'|;)+?;[ \t]*(?:%.*)?$
```

Finally, we invert all of this:

```
^(?!(?>[^%';\r\n]+|'(?>[^']+|'')*'|;)+?;[ \t]*(?:%.*)?$).+
```

And we have the final pattern. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK8zL5/1).

You don't need to fully tokenize the input, you only have to recognize the different "lexer modes". I hope handling strings and comments is enough, but I didn't check the Matlab syntax thoroughly.

You could use this with other regex engines that do not support atomic groups by replacing `(?>` with `(?:` but you'll expose yourself to the [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) problem.